# How to correctly DSolve it?

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

Solving a PDE with Mathematica, I obtain

```
sol = DSolve[Sqrt[D[u[x, y], x]] + Sqrt[D[u[x, y], y]] == x, u, {x, y}]
```

> `{{u -> Function[{x, y}, x^3/3 + 2 x^2 y + (x^2 C[1])/2 + x y C[1] + (x C[1]^2)/4 + (y C[1]^2)/4 - x y Sqrt[(2 x + C[1])^2] + C[2]]}}`

with a warning (not an error) "DSolve::nlpde: Solution requested to nonlinear partial differential equation. Trying to build a special solution". Unfortunately, the result is not correct, as

```
FullSimplify[(Sqrt[D[u[x, y], x]] + Sqrt[D[u[x, y], y]] /. 
sol) /. {C[1] -> 1}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

> `(1 + x)`

shows. The question arises: how to correctly DSolve this PDE?

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 doesn't evaluate `sol` ! What's your  version ?

Comment: 12.3 on Windows 10 Pro. You may try it in MathematicaOnline.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 gives the same message but doesn't find a special solution. Perhaps more trustworthy than the wrong result of v12.3?

Comment: BTW, Maple correctly finds a special solution $$u\! \left(x,y\right)=\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\sqrt{\textit{_}c_{2}}\, x^{2}+\textit{_}c_{2} x+\textit{_}\mathit{C1}+\textit{_}c_{2} y+\textit{_}\mathit{C2}.$$